# Editing Photoshop (PSD) files on Ubuntu?

Tags: files, photoshop

I was wondering that is it possible to edit PSD files on Ubuntu (like with Gimp). Actually, I need to edit layers. I haven't managed to do it. It would be nice if there is a chance! :)

Comment: Gimp should support PSDs out of the box....not 100% though.All layers should be rasterized in PS before saving if you want them to open correctly in Gimp. I don't have photoshop to test this.

Comment: Try https://www.Photopea.com. It supports layers, layer groups, layer styles, smart objects, adjustment layers ... You can also edit text layers and save everything back as a PSD file.

Answer (score 27):

You can have a look at Krita, even its look is close to Photoshop so you might feel at home easily when switching. Of course it is maybe not so blown up as Photoshop but it does its job well.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of Krita]

**Homepage:**

[https://krita.org](https://krita.org/)

Answer (score 13):

It not desktop software, but it looks to have active development. Try http://www.photopea.com

Comment: Now have multilanguage support!