# What is the best way to open PSD file except via GIMP?

Tags: 16.04, gimp

I'm tired to open PSD clearly via GIMP, So I need another good way to open it.

Comment: Refer these questions i think these will give you an idea [Answer1](http://askubuntu.com/q/690477/592114) , [Answer 2](http://askubuntu.com/q/56042/592114). Also try using photoshop via wine.

Comment: *As @Mani commented* "Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/690477/592114 and http://askubuntu.com/q/56042/592114 . Also you can try running Photoshop via `wine`"